# Faster method to replace specific image links XPath /Preg_replace

Tags: php, dom, xpath, getattribute

I have written a small piece of code that loads HTML content. Processes each image and checks if it has a full URL set.

If not, it adds it.

Currently I am doing this with XPath.
But I get the feeling that the procedure gets quite CPU intensive.
Hence I would like to know if there would be a faster method for what I am doing currently.

The code I have written

```
        ///######## START A NEW DOM DOCUMENT
        $dom            = new DOMDocument;
        ///######## LOAD THE HTML INTO THE DOM DOCUMENT
        $dom->loadHTML($html);
        ///######## GET ALL IMAGES WITH XPath
        $Images         = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
        ///######## SETUP AN EMPTY SOURCE AND TARGET ARRAY
        $SourceArray    = $TargetArray = array();

        ///######## RUN THROUGH ALL SET IMAGE NODES
        foreach ($Images as $node) {
            ///######## GET THE URL ATTRIBUTE
            $SetURL = $node->getAttribute('src').PHP_EOL;

            ///######## IF THE URL DOES NOT START WITH HTTP
            if(substr($SetURL, 0, 4) != 'http'){
                ///######## SET THE URL TO THE SOURCE ARRAY
                $SourceArray[] = 'img src="'.$SetURL;
                ///######## SET THE TARGET URL
                $TargetArray[] = 'img src="'.__APPBASE__.'/'.$this->TEMPLATEDIR.'/'.$SetURL;
            }
        }
        ///######## REMOVE THE BREAKS FROM BOTH ARRAYS
        $SourceArray    = str_replace(PHP_EOL, NULL, $SourceArray);
        $TargetArray    = str_replace(PHP_EOL, NULL, $TargetArray);
        ///######## REPLACE THE HTML TEXT
        $html           = str_replace($SourceArray, $TargetArray, $html);

        ///######## UNSET THE VARIABLES {free up memory}
        unset($dom);
        unset($SourceArray);
        unset($TargetArray);
```

Comment: A feeling is a bad way of figuring things out. Also why not just fix the HTML content in a one-off event

Comment: Well.. What if I told you that I couldn't fix the HTML at the moment of saving. I want to set absolute URL's. But these can change per instance. Hence that's why I want to do this... But the point is... If you want to link an external image it will also get fixed. That is what I want to prevent.

Comment: It is not a good idea of using external web sites for images for your web site - that is most likely to break. Image links are more fragile than hyperlinks. (because people tend to bookmark the latter)

Comment: @Ed Heal , maybe but I still want to support this since the system I am creating should support all kind of outbound links and information. I don't care weather it works fine for one month and afterwards it is gone. Because it should store the data for just one week.